# Array not working, but shows std::bad_alloc (How to fix this?)

Tags: c++, arrays

just started studying c++ and i have to make a dynamic array with an function that gets the max array value and prints it. And there seems to be a problem with my code. What have i done wrong, please help (criticism is much appreciated):

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getmax(int* arr,int n)
{
    int res=arr[0];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (res<arr[i]) res=arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int*arr;
    int n;
    arr=new int[n];
    cout<<"Enter array length: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter array number "<<i+1<<". : ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int maxi;
    maxi=getmax(arr,n);
    cout<<"Biggest number in array is "<<maxi;
    delete[]arr;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a classical newbie error. When you do `new int[n];`, the resulting array is not resizable. It's size doesn't become magically bound to the value of `n`. Changing `n` after creating the array doesn't affect that array in any way. Because of that you need to assign the desired size of the array to `n` before doing `new int[n]`.

Comment: You create array before you ask user for it's length.

Comment: Sidenote: If you are permitted to, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a dynamically allocated array. You may still want to get a value for `n` before allocating. Presizing a vector can eliminate the need for `vector` to resize itself on the fly.

Comment: C++ programs run top-down, thus `int n; arr=new int[n];` doesn't work correctly since `n` is not initialized.

Comment: To add to user4581301's comment: In general, you shouldn't be using `new` or `delete` yourself until you have a *lot* more experience with C++ (and usually not even then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already seem to have fixed your problem, but since you asked for (constructive) criticism, you should really study modern C++. In modern C++ we only use bare pointers when there is no other way. We also leverage the standard library whenever it is appropriate to do so. Just these two things will quickly make you a much more powerful programmer and reduce the opportunity for mistakes, provided you study the language and the library.

Here is an example of your program applying these principles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cout<<"Enter array length: ";
    cin>>n;

    vector<int> arr(n); // Create a vector with n integers

    // Iterate over the vector
    for( auto i = arr.begin(); i != arr.end(); ++i )
    {
        cout<<"Enter array number "<< (i-arr.begin())+1 << ". : ";
        cin>>*i; // Assign the input to the vector element through the iterator
    }

    // Get an iterator pointing to the largest element in the vector
    auto maxi = max_element(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend());
    cout<<"Biggest number in array is "<< *maxi << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The `std::vector` constructor allocates the memory, and the destructor frees the memory when `arr` goes out of scope. No more tedious matching `new` and `delete`. When you need to extend the lifetime of an object beyond the current scope use smart pointers or containers that have the lifetime your object needs.